# SQL Update 2 Columns from 1 Case

Tags: sql

I have code that selects a price based on some logic. Our choices are Target Margin, Average Historical Price, and Market Price (and these have all been calculated). Sometimes, we want to ignore that logic and explicitly say "for this model, please use this price, instead of what it might've already picked". But I also hold which price I used. So this sets my price with no problem:

```
Update A
Set [Price] = Case
    When [Logic Override] = 1 THEN [Target Margin Price]
    When [Logic Override] = 2 THEN [Average Historical Price]
    When [Logic Override] = 3 THEN [Market Price]
    Else [Price]
    END
From PriceTable A
Where ([Logic Override] <> 4 and [Logic Override] is not null)
and [Model_ID] = Coalesce(NullIf(@ModelID, ''), [Model_ID])
```

What I want to be able to do is also set the [Pricing Method]. Must I create a whole new case statement when what I really want to do is set both Price and Pricing Method to, say, $20 and 'Target Margin', respectively, if the Logic Override is 1? I can't seem to get the right syntax to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple sql logic in all columns (as long as you are trying to update the same table).

Your desired results is confusing and not sure what you actually need but I hope this helps you get the idea of updating multiple columns with each different WHERE clauses. Which I think you are trying to ask.

```
 Update A
 Set [Price] = (Select Case
                    When [Logic Override] = 1 THEN [Target Margin Price]
                    When [Logic Override] = 2 THEN [Average Historical Price]
                    When [Logic Override] = 3 THEN [Market Price]
                    Else [Price]
                   END
                   From PriceTable A
                    Where ([Logic Override] <> 4 and [Logic Override] is not null)
                    and [Model_ID] = Coalesce(NullIf(@ModelID, ''), [Model_ID]),

      [Pricing Method] = (Select '$20' as [Pricing Method] from PriceTable A where [logic 
      Override] = 1),

      [Price] =  (Select '$20' as [Price] from PriceTable A where [logic Override] = 1),
      [Target Margin]  = (Select '$20' as [Target Margin] from PriceTable A where [logic Override] = 1)

From PriceTable
```

I don't actually recommend these types of Updates because they are hard to maintain (if there multiple logic, tables, etc. that needs to be updated, this is cumbersome). I recommend that you create an update for each column so its easier to maintain, read and understood by your peers. But to each his own.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That's probably the best idea. I just thought it would be easier to maintain if it was all together. I'm a long-time Access developer and I could do it very easily with a "Select Case" statement and was hoping for something like that with SQL. I asked because I completely forgot the second part for the Pricing Method (which I'm pretty sure I had in there at some point, but must've gotten deleted somewhere along the line in testing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write them as two separate Case Statements back to back and only the first one updated the price. The second one did not update at all. So it picked the right price, but not the right pricing method.  Here is what actually worked.

```
Update A
Set [Price] = Case
When [Logic Override] = 1 THEN [Target Margin Price]
When [Logic Override] = 2 THEN [Average Historical Price]
When [Logic Override] = 3 THEN [Market Price]
Else [FRP]
END,

[Pricing Method] = Case
When [Logic Override] = 1 THEN 'Target Margin'
When [Logic Override] = 2 THEN 'Historical Average'
When [Logic Override] = 3 THEN 'Market Price'
Else [FRP]
END

From PriceTable A
Where ([Logic Override] <> 0 and [Logic Override] is not null)
and [Model_ID] = Coalesce(NullIf(@ModelID, ''), [Model_ID])
```

I'm really not sure why I wasn't able to use two separate update statements, but since this works, I'm not too worried about it. It's more code than I wanted to have, but I'm not too worried about it since it works.